# JqueryUI Dialog. Unable to trigger from html form

Tags: jquery-ui, modal-dialog

Works fine with a text link to fire dialog - but lasts for about .5 second if triggered from an html form submit button. Sounds crazy! Yep, just cannot get it to work. Help!

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rating-0').click(function() { $('#dialog').dialog('open'); }); $('#dialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false, height: 280, modal: true, resizable: false, buttons: { Continue: function() {
      $(this).dialog('close'); // Submit Rating 
    }, 'Change Rating': function() {
      $(this).dialog('close'); // Update Rating
    } }
    });
  });

<form action="https://www.etc" id="rating-0"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
  <input name="submit" type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" /> 
</form> 
<div id="dialog" title="Are you sure?"> 
  <p>You've assigned the current celebrity a rating of 0…</p> <p>Perhaps you are just judging them on the terrible last movie…</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please post some markup? It makes it hard to help if we can't see what you've done.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#rating-0').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
  });
  
  $('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 280,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: {
      Continue: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        // Submit Rating
      },
      'Change Rating': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        // Update Rating
      }
    }
  });
});

Comment: <form action="https://www.etc" id="rating-0">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input name="submit" type="image"  src="https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif"  />
  </form>
  
     <div id="dialog" title="Are you sure?">
  <p>You've assigned the current celebrity a rating of 0…</p>
  <p>Perhaps you are just judging them on the terrible last movie…</p>
      </div>

Answer (score 1):

Add `return false;` to your `submit` or `click` handler to prevent the browser from submitting the form and reloading the page.

**EDIT**:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rating-0').submit(function() { 
         $('#dialog').dialog('open'); 
         return false;
     }); 
     ...
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Slaks. I need a bit more help please! I am not too ofay with jquery .. where exactly should i insert 'return false' .. see scripts above. Thanks

Comment: @Rosy: You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.

Comment: i think also he didn't use the submit event as you mention he used the click event for the form witch is wrong